# Non-pointer class member: how good is it?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a non-pointer class member that I need to initialize in the constructor:

```
class Alerter {

protected:
  Timer timer;

public:
  Alerter(int interval);
};
```

and then

```
Alerter::Alerter(int interval) {
    timer = createTimer(interval);
}
```

(simplified code just to demonstrate the problem).

I have some doubts and concerns that `timer` probably is first created using its parameter-less constructor and later that instance is overwritten by the contents that the `createTimer` function returns.

How good is the approach? The possible answers could be:

- The "empty timer" created by its parameter-less constructor is not actually created, as the compiler is smart enough to find we have never
  referenced it before overwriting the value.
- The empty timer is created, but this is OK as well-written code should support a cheap parameter-less constructor for throwaway instances.
- It's better to use pointers.

Which of these assumptions (or maybe something else) is the most correct?

Comment: Can't you use a constructor initializer list to construct `timer`?

Comment: If you have appropriate constructor in `Timer` class you can just `Alerter::Alerter(int interval) : timer{ interval }{}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`timer` is first default-constructed and then assigned. Of course you can make assumption about how cheap a `Timer` is to default-construct or about compiler optimization, but here you don't need this since can prevent default-construction by using an initializer list:

```
Alerter::Alerter(int interval) : timer(createTimer(interval)) { }
```

This will work, unless your `Timer` class is copy-assignable but not copy-constructible, which would be weird.

Comment: default construction could also be prevented by declaring the default ctor `deleted`. This would enforce the use of an initializer list

Comment: "move-constructible" is sufficient since C++11 anyway, and neither is required starting from C++17 due to (a lack of) temporary materialization.

Answer (score 3):

**Both constructor will be called (and then the assignment as well).**

I have extended your example:

```
class Timer
{
  public:
    Timer() : m_interval(0)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor withOUT parameter has been called." << std::endl;
    }

    Timer(int interval) : m_interval(interval)
    {
        std::cout << "Constructor with parameter has been called." << std::endl;
    }

    Timer(const Timer& timer)
    {
        std::cout << "Copy constructor has been called." << std::endl;
        m_interval = timer.m_interval;
    }

    Timer(Timer&& timer)
    {
        std::cout << "Move constructor has been called." << std::endl;
        m_interval = timer.m_interval;
    }

    void operator=(Timer&& timer)
    {
        std::cout << "Move assignment has been called." << std::endl;
        m_interval = timer.m_interval;
    }

  private:
    int m_interval;
};

class Alerter
{
  protected:
    Timer timer;

  public:
    Alerter(int interval)
    {
        timer = Timer(interval);
    }
};

... 
Alerter alerter(12);
...
```

Output:

```
Constructor withOUT parameter has been called.
Constructor with parameter has been called.
Move assignment has been called.
```

And answering your question. It is better if the member variables are initialized only once but this is not a hard rule. For example, if the Timer is a very complex object but the default constructor creates just a dummy object, it is not too expensive and acceptable.

So, if you can avoid, better to avoid. Using pointer is a possible solution, but note the followings:

- Better to use `std::unique_ptr` to avoid memory leaks.
- This surely will require a heap memory allocation operation. If the objects are anyway on the heap (e.g. uses complex internal structures, like STL containers), it is not a problem. But if the objects are quite simple and the main use case is to create them as local objects, this can cause quite a big performance penalty. This should be a conscious design decision.